# Cause of System.NotSupportedException when converting a normal class to a web-service class

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to convert a normal (*.cs*) class to a web-service (*.asmx.cs*)class. I am not so pro in web-service and to convert it I just copied each and every function of this class to  *Service1.asmx.cs* web service class and added `[WebMethod]` on top of all functions. But the problem is, when I am writing these functions by hand, it is working, but when I just copy-pasted the remaining functions and added `[WebMethod]` on top of them, it showed me

> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member
>   System.Exception.Data of type System.Collections.IDictionary, because
>   it implements IDictionary.

I can't write those functions by hand. There are about 50 functions in that class. But I am unable to get the cause of this exception. I removed the constructor of the class. I checked all the functions, they are working fine when executed from normal class. They are all public functions. Please tell me the cause and solution to this.

Comment: Why did you use a .ASMX? ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: actually I am just a starter in using web-service. I only know traditional asmx.

Comment: It's not a "tradition". It's left-over. It has been kept only so that people can continue to maintain existing services. You should **not** use it for new development.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'd argue that WebAPI is acceptable for new development as well

Comment: @DanielMann: I said nothing about WebAPI. I said that ASMX should not be used.

Comment: @JohnSaunders You said that *WCF should be used for all new development of web services*, which could lead to confusion to someone considering using WebAPI over WCF.

Comment: ya @JohnSaunders now I am confused which one is better, please clarify anyone.

Comment: @DanielMann: good point. I meant SOAP-based web services.

Comment: @ShivaPareek: simply do not use ASMX. It should not be used for new development. If you need to create SOAP web services, then you should use WCF. The only time you should use ASMX is if you physically cannot use it. For instance, if you were developing in .NET 2.0, then you would have no other choices for SOAP web services.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of service technology (I started with asmx and moved to WCF) IDictionary is not a viable thing to return through a service interface especially if your endpoint is SOAP or http based. Objects in or out through the service interface have to be serializable, which IDictionary is not.